# Why do we use the aiter() Built-in Function in Python?

Tags: python-3.10

In Python 3.10 we see a newly-built-in function `aiter(async_iterable)`.

In [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#aiter), the definition is to *"Return an asynchronous iterator for an asynchronous iterable"*, but I can't understand how to use or not use this definition with an example from Google or YouTube. Does anyone know how to use this built-in function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aiter()` and `anext()` call an object's `__aiter__()` and `__anext__()`, if present. They're essentially the async equivalent of `iter()` and `next()`. In most cases, you'll want to simply use an `async for`, instead. However, to understand what `aiter()` and `anext()` are doing, the coroutines `using_async_for()` and `using_aiter_anext()` in the following example are roughly equivalent:

```py
from asyncio import sleep, run

class Foo:
    def __aiter__(self):
        self.i = 0
        return self
    async def __anext__(self):
        await sleep(1)
        self.i += 1
        return self.i

async def using_async_for():
    async for bar in Foo():
        print(bar)
        if bar >= 10:
            break

async def using_aiter_anext():
    ai = aiter(Foo())
    try:
        while True:
            bar = await anext(ai)
            print(bar)
            if bar >= 10:
                break
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        return

async def main():
    print("Using async for:")
    await using_async_for()

    print("Using aiter/anext")
    await using_aiter_anext()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```