# NameError: name 'aiter' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Getting an error on the below code. Any help is appreciated!

```py
async def numbers(num):
    for i in range(num):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def check_odd(num):
    it = aiter(numbers(num))
    while True:
        x = await anext(it, 'end')
        if x == 'end':
            break
        elif x % 2 != 0:
            print(f"{x} is Odd!!")

if __name__ == " __main__":
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.run_until_complete(check_odd(10))
    finally:
        event_loop.close()

nest_asyncio.apply()
asyncio.run(check_odd(10))
```

### Getting an error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-1f10e3e2fb22> in <module>()
     25 
     26 nest_asyncio.apply()
---> 27 asyncio.run(check_odd(10))

4 frames
<ipython-input-108-1f10e3e2fb22> in check_odd(num)
      9 
     10 async def check_odd(num):
---> 11     it = aiter(numbers(num))
     12     while True:
     13         x = await anext(it, 'end')

NameError: name 'aiter' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin function [`aiter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#aiter) and its related friend [`anext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#anext) (which is also in the code provided) are only introduced after Python 3.10 as per [this section of the release notice](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#other-language-changes).  Either change it to use the non-async counterpart (i.e. use `iter`/`next` if possible) or use Python 3.10 or later to run the relevant program.  A [related thread on `aiter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209180/why-we-use-aiter-built-in-function-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: ah ok, Let me try iter/next. Thank you for your response! @metatoaster

Comment: @sukanya Note that you can't `await` on `next`, it would completely change the async nature of the example program, so you need to know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @metatoaster The question is tagged with `python-3.10`, so apparently they're already using that.

Comment: @metatoaster I am trying to learn how aiter and await works, will work with more examples to understand them. Thank you for mentioning that "can't await on next".